# WPF ListBox Virtualization and Mulltiple types in the ItemsControl

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listbox, virtualization

I've got a ListBox that is used to show items of multiple types (all derived from the same base type) that are bound to the ItemsSource through an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

The performance of said ListBox is terrible. It appears that virtualization is disabled. According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.110).aspx it seems that adding items of multiple types to the ItemsControl may be the problem.

Here's my ListBox's style:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling" />
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource ListHeader}" />

                        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" Focusable="False">
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

There are DataTemplates for each of the possible types in the bound `ObservableCollection<T>` and they are all classes that derive from the same base class. An example DataTemplate is:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ma:TimerEvent}">
            <Grid Background="{StaticResource TargetCalledBackgroundColor}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ShotNumberColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ShotTimeColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="SplitTimeColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="TargetNumberColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="TotalTimeColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ScoreColumn" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Source="/LASR;component/Assets/Announcement.png" Width="16" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="{StaticResource TargetCalledForegroundColor}" Text="{Binding DisplayText}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Foreground="{StaticResource TargetCalledForegroundColor}" Text="{Binding TargetNumberCalled}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Foreground="{StaticResource TargetCalledForegroundColor}" Text="{Binding Path=TotalTime.TotalSeconds, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}" TextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

ListBox XAML is here:

```
<UserControl>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The WPF window's hierarchy is:

```
<Window>
<Grid>
 <Grid Name="MainWindowContent">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="340*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <UserControl />
    </Grid>
   </GroupBox>
  </Grid>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

Is there a solution to this problem or can anyone see any other reason virtualization may be turned off?

You can download [an example project here](http://www.centrolutions.com/downloads/ListPerformance.zip).

Thanks.

Comment: Adding different types of **Data** items does NOT affect virtualization. MSDN says: *Item **containers** are added directly to the ItemsControl.*. That would be a `ListBoxItem` and a `ComboBoxItem`, for example.

Comment: make sure you're not putting the ListBox inside an "infinite container" such as a StackPanel or a ScrollViewer. Post the full XAML of the UI where the ListBox is located.

Comment: Also, what are the types of your data items?

Comment: All of the data items are derived from the same base class. The ListBox is located inside of a UserControl that has a Grid as its container.

Comment: The user control is contained within several grids and a GroupBox, but no StackPanels

Comment: is that the full XAML? don't you have any `RowDefinitions` in the outer Grid?

Comment: I updated the question with the Window's hierarchy. Are grid rows that  have height defined as "*" considered "infinite containers?"

Comment: @JasonWilliams It's considered that all children will be equally divided to fit the content.

Comment: I am not following this:  There are DataTemplates for each of the possible types. Where are you doing that?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. I updated the question with an example DataTemplate. They live in the resources of the UserControl.

Comment: I just added a bounty and an example project.

Comment: Why are you doing all that with Shared size scopes to "imitate" a ListView instead of just using a ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance in your sample project is **drastically** improved by removing the `ColumnDefinitions` with `SharedSizeGroups`:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ShotNumberColumn" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ShotTimeColumn" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="SplitTimeColumn" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="TargetNumberColumn" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="TotalTimeColumn" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ScoreColumn" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The calculations needed for `SharedSizeGroup` are too heavy and should be avoided if you have large number of items.

Use a `ListView` instead.

Comment: The ListBox lets me use a different template for each data type in the list.
Some of the types have different background colors, sometimes the first column is an image, at times a columnspan is used, etc. That's why this scheme was chosen over a ListView.

Comment: I have confirmed that the performance problem is indeed tied to the SharedSizeGroup property on the grid columns. It appears that virtualization on the ListBox was never the problem. I appreciate the answer!