# Why is the ListBox display slow when I scroll?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Why is the ListBox display slow when I scroll?  The tabs align fine.  But when I scroll (more than 500 lines), it scrolls fine, but is slow in re-aligning the columns.

Is there a faster way?

In the xlam I have:

```
<ListBox Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" x:Name="gLBxDbContactInfo" >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Grid> <!--used for tab locations-->
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Col0"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Col1"/>
  ...
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Col9"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding tabNameLastFirst}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding tabAdr}"/>
...
<TextBlock Grid.Column="9" Text="{Binding tabOtherInfo}"/>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In the .cs I have

```
//=================
public class ListBoxTabs
{
  public string tabNameLastFirst { get; set; }
  public string tabAdr { get; set; }
  ...
  public string tabOtherInfo { get; set; }
}// class ListBoxTabs
//=================
```

and

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < iNum; ii++)
{
 g.ParseStringToListst(gliststDbData[ii], liststParsed, '\t');
 listItems.Add(new ListBoxTabs() {
   tabNameLastFirst = liststParsed[0],
   tabAdr = " " + liststParsed[4],
   ...
   tabOtherInfo = " " + liststParsed[12]
  });
  liststParsed.Clear();
}
```

Comment: If you're not tied to using the `ListBox` control in particular, a `ListView` or `DataGrid` control might be a better fit for what it looks like you're doing (presumably displaying a list of items with multiple columns for each item).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23019795/643085

Comment: In ListView, is there a way to set the width to be automatic?

Comment: @ttom If you mean getting the list view columns to autosize themselves, then no I don't think this is supported without workarounds. The `DataGrid` control *does* support autosized columns, so I am told (I've never used it so can't verify). However the SO answer linked to by HighCore should help if you want to use a list box with grid elements for autosizing.